# How to add machine type to Intel fortran VS2019 bat file built dll filename

Tags: batch-file, cmd, fortran, resources, intel-fortran

Intel fortran parallel studio in VS2019 provides two cmd shortcuts, each sets the environment appropriately for either a 32bit or 64bit compiler command line build. The process window title includes this compiler type name.
I am running a bat file that compiles .f90s to give .obj files and combines them to build a dll for use with 32 bit or 64 bit excel. I am therefore running it in both 32 and 64 bit compiler cmd processes. All of this works well. But is there a way for the bat to get the cmd process name, ie whether I am building the dll for 32 bit or 64 bit and add to this to the stringfileinfo or the dll filename? Currently both get the same filename and version info.

Answer (score 0):

```
tasklist /v |find "whatever the window-title or part-title or processname is">nul
```

should set `errorlevel` to 0 if the title, etc. is found, non-zero otherwise.